# Dynamic size for data type in MySQL

Tags: mysql, types, varchar

I want to save a string in a column of table in MySQL. Sometimes it is 2 characters and sometimes very larger. 50000 characters. Is it a good idea to user varchar(50000). If I only save 2 characters in the column, does it use all 4998 bytes or just 2 bytes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As documented under [Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/storage-requirements.html):

> #### Storage Requirements for String Types
>
> In the following table, ***`M`*** represents the declared column length in characters for nonbinary string types and bytes for binary string types. ***`L`*** represents the actual length in bytes of a given string value.
>
> ```
> ╔═════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
> ║          Data Type          ║                Storage Required                 ║
> ╠═════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
> ║ CHAR(M)                     ║ M × w bytes, 0 <= M <= 255, where w is the      ║
> ║                             ║ number of bytes required for the maximum-length ║
> ║                             ║ character in the character set                  ║
> ╠═════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
> ║ BINARY(M)                   ║ M bytes, 0 <= M <= 255                          ║
> ╠═════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
> ║ VARCHAR(M), VARBINARY(M)    ║ L + 1 bytes if column values require 0 – 255    ║
> ║                             ║ bytes, L + 2 bytes if values may require more   ║
> ║                             ║ than 255 bytes                                  ║
> ╠═════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
> ║ TINYBLOB, TINYTEXT          ║ L + 1 bytes, where L < 28                         ║
> ╠═════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
> ║ BLOB, TEXT                  ║ L + 2 bytes, where L < 216                        ║
> ╠═════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
> ║ MEDIUMBLOB, MEDIUMTEXT      ║ L + 3 bytes, where L < 224                        ║
> ╠═════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
> ║ LONGBLOB, LONGTEXT          ║ L + 4 bytes, where L < 232                        ║
> ╠═════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
> ║ ENUM('value1','value2',...) ║ 1 or 2 bytes, depending on the number of        ║
> ║                             ║ enumeration values (65,535 values maximum)      ║
> ╠═════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
> ║ SET('value1','value2',...)  ║ 1, 2, 3, 4 or 8 bytes, depending on the number  ║
> ║                             ║ of set members (64 members maximum)             ║
> ╚═════════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
> ```
>
> Variable-length string types are stored using a length prefix plus data. The length prefix requires from one to four bytes depending on the data type, and the value of the prefix is ***`L`*** (the byte length of the string). For example, storage for a [`MEDIUMTEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html) value requires ***`L`*** bytes to store the value plus three bytes to store the length of the value.
>
> To calculate the number of bytes used to store a particular [`CHAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/char.html), [`VARCHAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/char.html), or [`TEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html) column value, you must take into account the character set used for that column and whether the value contains multi-byte characters. In particular, when using the `utf8` (or `utf8mb4`) Unicode character set, you must keep in mind that not all characters use the same number of bytes and can require up to three (four) bytes per character. For a breakdown of the storage used for different categories of `utf8` or `utf8mb4` characters, see [Section 10.1.10, “Unicode Support”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-unicode.html).
>
> [`VARCHAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/char.html), [`VARBINARY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/binary-varbinary.html), and the [`BLOB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html) and [`TEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html) types are variable-length types. For each, the storage requirements depend on these factors:
>
> - The actual length of the column value
> - The column's maximum possible length
> - The character set used for the column, because some character sets contain multi-byte characters
>
> For example, a `VARCHAR(255)` column can hold a string with a maximum length of 255 characters. Assuming that the column uses the `latin1` character set (one byte per character), the actual storage required is the length of the string (***`L`***), plus one byte to record the length of the string. For the string `'abcd'`, ***`L`*** is 4 and the storage requirement is five bytes. If the same column is instead declared to use the `ucs2` double-byte character set, the storage requirement is 10 bytes: The length of `'abcd'` is eight bytes and the column requires two bytes to store lengths because the maximum length is greater than 255 (up to 510 bytes).

Therefore, in answer your question:

> If I only save 2 characters in the column, does it use all 4998 bytes or just 2 bytes?

A `VARCHAR(50000)` column storing a 2-character string would require ***`L`***+2 bytes, where ***`L`*** is the number of bytes required to encode that 2-character string in the column's character set: it certainly *will not* use "all 4998 bytes".

Comment: So what do you suggest me to use? text, varchar or char to?

Comment: @SpongeBob: It depends on how often the data is short and how often it's long.  If it's usually short, I'd prefer `VARCHAR` (the data will be stored within the row records and therefore readily available); whereas if it's usually long, I'd prefer `TEXT` (the data will be stored elsewhere and therefore won't slow table scans or contribute toward maximum row size).  You can't use `CHAR` in this case, as it has a maximum size of 255 characters (and in any event it would be very expensive to store sparse data in such a column).

Comment: Well, I would prefer to use varchar(50000). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

You have this **varchar** datatype in MySQL for dynamic memory allocation of data which is **variable length**. So if you save 2 chars it'll occupy only 2 chars memory space and if you save 50000 chars it'll occupy 50000 chars memory space. Refer this [mysql link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)